# Any free mobile IDEs that run on a Blackberry?

Tags: ide, blackberry, java-me

I was just wondering if there were any IDEs that I can run on my blackberry. My old Palm had on board C and a BASIC interpreter. On board C used the Palm's builtin text editor but the BASIC interpreter had its own simple editor built in.

Anything like this for Blackberry or j2me in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no Basic or C interpreters or IDEs that run specifically on the BlackBerry, but there is an open source J2ME basic dialect called **CellularBasic** which is meant to be coded with/executed on the device itself. It targets J2ME, so it may run on the BlackBerry: http://cellbasic.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a [Hecl](http://www.hecl.org) port for BlackBerry, but it's not quite there yet.  If you're curious, join the Google Group, where I post updates about the state of things.